# FastApi with gunicorn/uvicorn stops responding

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, gunicorn, uvicorn

I'm currently using **FastApi** with **Gunicorn**/**Uvicorn** as my server engine.

I'm using the following config for **Gunicorn**:

```
TIMEOUT 0
GRACEFUL_TIMEOUT 120
KEEP_ALIVE 5
WORKERS 10
```

**Uvicorn** has all default settings, and is started in docker container casually:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Everything is packed in docker container.

**The problem is the following:**

After some time (somewhere between 1 day and 1 week, depending on load) my app stops responding (even simple `curl http://0.0.0.0:8000` command hangs forever). Docker container keeps working, there are no application errors in logs, and there are no connection issues, but none of my workers are getting the request (and so I'm never getting my response). It seems like my request is lost somewhere between server engine and my application. Any ideas how to fix it?

**UPDATE**: I've managed to reproduce this behaviour with custom **locust** load profile:[image: load picture]
The scenario was the following:

1. In first 15 minutes ramp up to 50 users (30 of them will send requests requiring GPU at 1 rps, and 20 will send requests that do not require GPU at 10 rps)
2. Work for another 4 hours
   As the plot shows, in about 30 minutes API stops responding. (And still, there are no error messages/warnings in output)

**UPDATE 2**:
Can there be any hidden memory leak or deadlock due to incorrect **Gunicorn** setup or bug (such as https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/596)?

**UPDATE 4**:
I've got inside my container and executed `ps` command. It shows:

```
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
    120 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
    134 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

Which means my **Gunicorn** server app just silently turned off. And also there is binary file named `core` in the app directory, which obviously mens that something has crashed

Comment: @Chris no it's not. I'm getting this error no matter if I face CUDA memory overflow or not.

Comment: @Chris P.S. I've moved away all ML models to a separate container, but API keeps failing.

Comment: Without looking at your application source code it's hard to help, but the first thing I'd double check is that you are handling database connections correctly. When your application gets to "hanging forever state", query your database and check for open connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an **Out Of Memory error** (OOM). The leak was caused by `elastic apm` middleware. I removed it, and leak disappeared.

Comment: how did you figure out what caused this and how did you confirm it was an OOM issue, I'm facing a similar issue

Comment: @Ebdulmomen1 Just got `docker stats` and watched my container memory to flow away. When I removed middleware it stopped